# метод flush не определяется

Tags: java, eclipse

При попытке вызова метода .flush, данный метод не определяется.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

public class ByteReader 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    FileInputStream myFile = null;
    BufferedInputStream buff= null;
    
    try
    {
        myFile = new FileInputStream("c:\\workspace\\ezgif-2-093c394088ea.gif");
        buff = new BufferedInputStream(myFile);
        
        while(true)
        {
            int byteValue = buff.read();
            System.out.println( byteValue + " " );
            
            if ( byteValue == - 1)
            {
                break;
            }
         }
        }
        
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Невозможно прочитать файл, ошибка : " + e.toString());
        }
        
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                buff.flush();
                buff.close();
                myFile.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Чтение файла завершено успешно");
        
 }
 }
 }
```

[image: код java]

Comment: flush у OutputStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush(). Чего вы рассчитывали добиться этим методом?

Comment: так и есть, спасибо), надеялся наверное дочитать файл)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flush нужен для OutputStream, а вы используете его для InputStream

Answer (score 1):

у `BufferedInputStream` нету метода `flush`, ссылка на [доку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html).

Поэтому eclipse вам подчеркивает метод`flush()`.